# AccessPoint doesn't allow me to connect my device to raspberry

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux, dhcp, hostapd

I am trying to configure an Wifi access point on my raspberry. I have created a virtual interface that enables my RPI (3B+) to still use wlan0 for wifi connection and "apwlan0" for accesspoint. I just need my RPI to be able to be connected to, via wifi (not bluetooth or ethernet) when no other network is available. i have followed this user's answer:

[Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge/89804#89804)

I have many files that I changed exactly like he did I haven't touched the dhcpd.conf. but here is the files modified:

`hostapd.conf`

```
driver=nl80211
ssid=RPidaq
country_code=FR
hw_mode=g
channel=1
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=verySecretPassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

The new service (called accesspoint@wlan0.service when running)

`accesspoint@.service (edited)`

```
[Unit]
Description=accesspoint with hostapd (interface-specific version)
Wants=wpa_supplicant@%i.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw dev %i interface add ap@%i type __ap
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd -i ap@%i /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
ExecStopPost=-/sbin/iw dev ap@%i del

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
```

Created a new conf file for the wlan0 AP

`wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf`

```
country=FR
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="RPIdaq"
    psk="SamePass"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK   
}
```

And finally edited the wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service

`wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service (edited)`

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=accesspoint@%i.service
After=accesspoint@%i.service
```

Then created two files for static IP adresses for both interfaces wlan0 and apwlan0

Problem is when i reboot my RPI, wifi works fine, apwlan0 is displayed, i can see ssid:RPIdaq on my phone, but can't connect to it. The `accesspoint@wlan0.service` is loaded but failed for active and waiting. This is the output for `sudo systemctl status accesspoint@wlan0.service`:

```
● accesspoint@wlan0.service - accesspoint with hostapd
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/accesspoint@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-04-16 16:30:54 CEST; 24min ago
  Process: 4325 ExecStartPre=/sbin/iw dev wlan0 interface add apwlan0 type __ap (code=exited, status=240/LOGS_DIRECTORY)
  Process: 4326 ExecStopPost=/sbin/iw dev ap@i del (code=exited, status=237/KEYRING)

Apr 16 16:30:54 PFema systemd[1]: Starting accesspoint with hostapd...
Apr 16 16:30:54 PFema iw[4325]: command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)
Apr 16 16:30:54 PFema systemd[1]: accesspoint@wlan0.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=240/LOGS_DIRECTORY
Apr 16 16:30:54 PFema iw[4326]: command failed: No such device (-19)
Apr 16 16:30:54 PFema systemd[1]: accesspoint@wlan0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 16 16:30:54 PFema systemd[1]: Failed to start accesspoint with hostapd.
```

If you have any tips or an idea on what is happening. I would gladly take it. To give a better idea of the function I am searching for, I am trying to enable my RPI to be accessed wirelessly from a phone. And when the connection is made, the RPI will show a dashboard on a web browser of datas and such.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: With further research, now i can see the RPI AP from my phone but cannot connect to it apparently, the password is wrong... But still accesspoint@wlan0.service fails to load.

Comment: Are you trieing to run both a AP and a client connection of the integrated Wifi Chip?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to be able to connect to the RPI with my phone with WIFI. And still be able to have my RPI connected to my router for internet use. The only use for the AP is I want to create a web interface, so my phone can interact with the PI easily when no internet is around.